# Forward ForeignKey querying in Django

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following two models:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    ...


class Keyword(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(...)

    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', related_name="keywords")
```

Now lets say I want to return a list of all posts for a given `keyword.value`.

I usually do this:

```py
keywords = Keyword.object.filter(value="something").values_list(id, flat=True)`. 

Posts.keywords.filter(id__in=keywords)
```

To return a `<QuerySet[]>` of `Post`s.

I'm not sure if I am missing something in the documentation, but can I return a QuerySet of Posts in ***one query*** and can I do it on the `Keyword` model? Something similar to a related name set ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a `queryset` of `Post`s if you query the `Keyword` model.

IIUC you can narrow to a single query by doing:

```
Post.objects.filter(keywords__value__in=['something'])
```